# how can i store rich text formatting in XML that pulls out to my page formatted

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am storing user inputs through a form with wiki style formatting (*text* for bold, _text for underline, etc) in my database. I was planning to use the db functions & some page code to store all of the info out to XML with the proper html formatting for each rich text field included. From there the XML gets parsed with an XSL stylesheet. The one thing I haven't been able to figure out is how to get the HTML to appear as HTML. I can get it to show the code on screen but not the formatted html.

Does any one know of a way to 
A) get the html in the xml file and have it appear on screen as formatted html or
B) how to find/replace my wiki formatting with html with the XSL

Comment: This question is too-general. Without specific examples of the XML document(s) involved and the required result, it is like asking for a program that has no specific input and no specific output...

Please redefinr the question in order to have a better chance of being understood and answered.

Comment: Agree with the above comment but more specifically, how do you 'get' the HTML onto the screen. I would suggest an innerHTML property using JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand you correctly, you have some xml with html formatting in it, something like this:

```
<foo><strong>blah <a href="/">bar</a></strong></foo>
```

The xsl to display the html inside foo is:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thank you this is exactly what i needed. When I was writing out the XML I used value-of instead of copy-of. Thank you So much for the help!